# Ubuntu unable to use Kinect v1

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, kinect

I used Kinect on my ubuntu laptop, with a 12V adapter connect Kinect to usb.

But the light on Kinect is always flashing and when checking lsusb, I can sometimes see Motor plugin and NEC which I think is the 12V adapter. It is unstable because it sometimes occurred Motor and sometimes not. But NEC is always there.

I run glview and it shows `number of devices found: 0`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://sigmaoctantis.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/kinect-installation-in-ubuntu-14-10/comment-page-1/#comment-11

This guide works. try to follow its steps. If you are having trouble just recognizing the unit, what happens when you type `lsusb`  do you see any Xbox? you should see 3 lines

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).